# getting result for a query in pgAdmin console but not through my java code

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am hitting the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test_test 
where user_id_one = 123456789 
  and user_id_two = 123456788 
  and action_taken = 'CHECK' 
  and games_type = 'LUDDO' 
  and modified_on >= '2021-10-07 05:53:48'::timestamp 
  and modified_on < '2021-10-07 05:53:49'::timestamp
```

I am getting the result in pgAdmin console, but when I try the same thing using the Java code, it is not working:

```
ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM test_test where user_id_one = ? and user_id_two = ? and action_taken = ? and games_type = ? and modified_on >= ?::timestamp and modified_on < ?::timestamp");
ps.setInt(1,testTest.getUserIdOne());
ps.setInt(2,testTest.getUserIdTwo());
ps.setString(3,testTest.getActionTaken());
ps.setString(4,testTest.getGamesType());
ps.setString(5,new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(collusionDashboard.getModifiedOn().toDate()));
ps.setString(6,new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(collusionDashboard.getModifiedOn().plusSeconds(1).toDate()));
resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
log.info("{}",ps);
if (resultSet.next()) == getting false here {
           
        }
```

When I was logging the data, I am getting the same query as mentioned above.

Comment: you should not pass timestamp values as strings. Pass an instanace of `LocalDateTime`  using `setObject()`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to log the PrepareStatement object, try to to log the ResultSet object instead.